# MYSQL no access/privileges how to change from a useless user to root?

Tags: mysql

The problem I have is when I get into the commandline for mysql I enter as ''@'localhost' and have no access to anything useful, I'm trying at the moment to get data back to a php page so I need a valid username and password. Is there a way I can create a user account with my feeble resources? Is there a way I can enter the MySQL commandline as root?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried "mysql -u root"?

Answer (score 1):

If you user is *root* without any password (like a default MySQL setup), you should be able to connect using:

```
mysql --user=root
```

If you need to specify *pwd* as password:

```
mysql --user=root -ppwd
```

Check [MySQL command line guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_user) for other details.

Answer (score 0):

When you install MySQL, it asks you to enter credentials for the root user.
If you had not done something like that, I recommend you to reinstall.

Moreover, I would recommend you to use a good package like PHPMyadmin to simplify your operations with databases.
http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/news.php

You could also try Xampp, which has everything in a package - PHP, Tomcat, Mercury , Filezilla, PHPMyadmin and more if you'd like. You will spend almost 0 time configuring anything.
http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Answer (score 0):

Previously, I was getting `Access denied...` errors for every command, but I was able to resolve the issue after reading RobbieE's suggestion and [this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/default-privileges.html):

1. First, start `mysql` from the command line as the `root` user; this is the solution to your original question:

`mysql -u root`

Now if you'd like to password-protect `root`...

2. To see which accounts exist and check their passwords, execute:

`SELECT User, Host, Password FROM mysql.user;`

You should see an ASCII table, something like this:

```
+------+--------------------+----------+
| User | Host               | Password |
+------+--------------------+----------+
| root | localhost          |          |
| root | 127.0.0.1          |          |
|      | localhost          |          |
+------+--------------------+----------+
```

3. Finally, set the password for each `root` user a la:

`SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('plaintext-password');`

Re-execute statement 2 to verify the password was set correctly. You now have a useful and protected MySQL user for `localhost`. Do this again for `127.0.0.1` and any other hosts you may have.